# stellar.js window resize fails on responsive parallax elements

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, reload, parallax, stellar.js

I am using jQuery and stellar.js. On window resize stellar.js should reload the position, but it doesn't do anything. I already used:

```
$.stellar({ responsive: true });
```

Here is my demo trial:
http://www.webgarten.ch/responsive/

Comment: Put this in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) instead, much more easier than forcing us to inspect your demo site with Firebug (or similar).

Comment: Ok, sorry... here it is
http://jsfiddle.net/Oliver23/ke4p02fq/2/